# Tabela temporária com underscore

Tags: sql, sql-server, tabela-temporária

Estou tentando no meu serviço criar tabelas temporárias como sempre aprendi, colocando `#` na frente do nome que eu quero. Mas não sei o que acontece que quando crio uma, ele coloca um underscore enorme e umas coisas aleatórias depois do nome. Exemplo, criei a tabela `#TEMP`, aí ele cria a tabela `#TEMP___________________________________0000004`, conforme print.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Viva, que tal experimentar usar o Function Table? Funciona muito bem e trabalha directamente na memória do servidor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isso é uma característica do MS SQL Server. Ele adiciona esses `_` e depois um identificador para saber de qual conexão ela veio, assim se outra conexão criar uma tabela temporária com o mesmo nome não terá problemas.

Nada com o que se preocupar, pode continuar usando normalmente apenas com o `#temp`.

Mais informações: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19670997/266569

Comment: Muito obrigada!